# Connect AWS Hosted Zone To Registered domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I want to connect my domain (in AWS Registered Domains) to the IP address of my Ec2 instance in my AWS account; so that I can type `www.my-domain.com` in any browser and open my website.

I transferred a domain name from my old AWS account to a new one. Usually AWS creates a hosted zone for the domain automatically, but it didn't.

So I created my own hosted zone and and added and two A records ([www.a.com](http://www.a.com) and a.com) with value connected to the IP address of my Ec2 instance but the browsers didn't recognize the domain.

So I tried:

1. Updating the Name servers of the hosted zone to be the same as the domain name NS **But same result**
2. Updating the Name servers of the domain name to be the same as the hosted zone NS **But same result**

What can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this could count as and answer but this is what I did to fix the problem:

1. I created and `Application Load Balancer`
2. With `Security Group` with Inbound rules: `HTTP TCP 80 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0`
3. And `Target Group` TCP 80 Set to Ec2 instance.
4. Connect the A record to the ALB

This fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

As long as the domain registrar is AWS (you can validate this by running `whois` against your domain) the setup should be quite simple.

Firstly it might be worth creating a new hosted zone if you've modified the `NS` records for it. It is important that these values are the original domains that AWS entered against the values. Also ensure the hosted zone is a **public** hosted zone.

Copy each of the nameserver values from your public hosted zone (there should be 4 in total). Then on your registered domain in the Route 53 console, edit the nameservers replacing the values with the values that were taken from your hosted zone. Once you have done this the new public hosted zone will be used by your domain.

Depending on any TTL caching you might find it can take a little time for clients to use this nameserver but you can test it by using a `DIG` command to find the `NS` value using an external server or the [web service offered by google](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/).

Comment: Right now the NS records of the hosted zone, is the same as the registered domain, but I still have the same problem

Comment: As for the ownership  of the domain the `Registrant contact` is my email and verified. Same for Administrative contact and Technical contact.

Comment: And the hosted zone is public

Comment: When you run DIG NS what does it return? And whois, does that display the registrar as Amazon?

Comment: I don't know how to open amazon cli I am only using the console. Yes I think the registar is amazon because I bought the domain from amazon and is registered in route 53 under registered domains. And the contacts of this domain are all connected to my personal email.

Comment: Paste your domain in https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/ and check `NS` :)

Comment: OK, and when you check the A record (via DIG) this returns the public IPv4 address of the instance?

Comment: I remove the Application Load Balancer and setted the A record to ec2 IP and now everything is fixed don't now why it didn't work before even though records in hosted zone were the same. as for dig NS it is returning the Ip correctly

Comment: I will re-add the ALB because I need to add SSL certificate to the website!

Comment: If the records cached either in your local network ot at your providers end then the records will go to the broken record. Once the cache has cleared it will work

Comment: Yup I think that was it